# Android Xamarin Bottom Navigation Bar overwrites the fragment and other view content

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

The library used for Bottom Navigation Bar is this - https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar

I had Navigation Drawer in my application, so I run into issue that Bottom Navigation Bar is above the Navigation Drawer. So I followed the suggestion that was provided in documentation:

> All you need to do is instead of attaching the BottomBar to your Activity, attach it to the view that has your content. For example, if your fragments are in a ViewGroup that has the id fragmentContainer

So I did just that:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // Some stuff

        bottomBar = BottomBar.Attach(this.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer), bundle);
        bottomBar.SetItems(Resource.Menu.bottombar_menu);
        bottomBar.SetOnMenuTabClickListener(this);
        bottomBar.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Bottom);

        var layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        layoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom;

        bottomBar.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        bottomBar.NoTopOffset();

        // Make a Badge for the first tab, with red background color and a value of "13".
        BottomBarBadge unreadMessages = bottomBar.MakeBadgeForTabAt(0, "#FF0000", 13);

        // Control the badge's visibility
        unreadMessages.Show();
        unreadMessages.Hide();

        // Change the displayed count for this badge.
        unreadMessages.Count = 4;

        // Change the show / hide animation duration.
        unreadMessages.AnimationDuration = 200;

        // If you want the badge be shown always after unselecting the tab that contains it.
        unreadMessages.AutoShowAfterUnSelection = true;

        var fragment = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragment.AddToBackStack(null);
        fragment.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, new CustomFragment());
        fragment.Commit();
    }
```

But unfortunately in result the [Bottom Navigation Bar is visible, but the content of Fragment is not](http://image.prntscr.com/image/193718d42a7f4e4e951f28960a06ab67.png).

I checked [UI Hierarchy](http://image.prntscr.com/image/e9eb1441b0bb43d2bf9bd08687737e26.png), my fragment content is not even added.

I also tried adding just simple LinearLayout under the view I attached Bottom Navigation Bar, it was also overriden by the Bottom Navigation Bar.

Here is my AXML for main activity view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
      <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <include
              layout="@layout/toolbar"
              android:id="@+id/app_bar"/>
        <ScrollView             
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">
            <FrameLayout
              android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
              android:minWidth="25px"
              android:minHeight="25px"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              />        
        </ScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

Here are additional resource files used:

bottom_bar.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarItem_Taken"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_download_white_48dp"
        android:title="" />
  <item
      android:id="@+id/bottomBarItem_Given"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_upload_white_48dp"
        android:title="" />
  <item
      android:id="@+id/bottomBarItem_Discover"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cached_white_48dp"
        android:title="" />
</menu>
```

nav_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_home"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
      android:title="Home" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_favorites"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
      android:title="Favorites" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_stuff"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_business_center_black_24dp"
      android:title="My Stuff" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_contacts"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts_black_24dp"
      android:title="Contacts" />
      <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_message_black_24dp"
    android:title="Messages" />
      <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_calendar"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_date_range_black_24dp"
    android:title="Calendar" />
      <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_payments"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_payment_black_24dp"
    android:title="Payments" />
      <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_history"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_black_24dp"
    android:title="History" />
  </group>
  <item>
    <menu>
      <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="Settings" />
      <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_systemNotifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
        android:title="System Notifications" />
      <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_support"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
        android:title="Support" />
      <item
     android:id="@+id/nav_aboutUs"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_outline_black_24dp"
     android:title="About Us" />
    </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

menu_header.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#00BCD4">
  <FrameLayout         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         />    
  </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearMenuHeader"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="John Johnson"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:typeface="sans" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="ONLINE"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide @menu/nav_menu, @layout/menu_header, @layout/toolbar files ?

Comment: You might be able to wait a little bit for the official binding to `Support v25` to come out which includes `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` so you can avoid using a third party lib.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: @YuriS Added resource files.

Comment: There are a lot of additional resource used. The best will be to put the project to dropbox or somewhere else, so I can just grab it.